# Instantiating an object

Tags: java, android

In java, i have learned that i use the new keyword to instantiate an object e.g

```
 Employee e = new Employee();
```

In android ,by going through the developers page a context object is instantiated without using the new keyword like this :

```
Context myContext = getApplicationContext();
```

Why is this ? i should have thought that a context object should be created the same way using new keyword like this:

```
Context myContext = new Context();
```

I think someone might answer back saying that the **getApplicationContext()** method returns an object of type context and hence the syntax above,but does someone have a more deeper explanation as to why do this instead of simply 
doing this

```
Context myContext = new Context();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because sometimes you simply don't want/need to create a new instance each time, sometimes you just want to get the object without actually handling its creation by yourself.

For example, there is a [Singleton design pattern](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjIyqrJtoHNAhWGXCwKHRq8ADwQFggyMAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSingleton_pattern&usg=AFQjCNGbZGGNDuJrNFR0uvIZGFpSvp7SOg&sig2=zoP0cM0JyssgsZWVJG-uVA&bvm=bv.123325700,d.bGg) that in its common implementation makes it impossible to create a new instance with a `new` keyword since a constructor is private. So what is left to do is get an instance of a class by calling a static method:

```
public class MySingleton {
    private MySingleton() { }

    public static MySingleton getInstance() { ... }
}
```

Sometimes you may want to use a [Factory method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), that handles new object creation/instantiation as well: you call a single method and a new or existing object is returned for you without explicitly calling a constructor.

In case of Context, you don't need to create this object, because the system handles it for you and the process is transparent. You just need to call a single method and you have your instance.

Comment: This is very useful info thanks, i never knew about Factory method pattern untill now ,is getApplicationContext() an example of a factory method ?

Comment: Factory methods create objects that they return, and application's context already exists by the time you call getApplicationContext(), so no, this is not exactly a factory method. In this case we are closer to Singleton since the returned object is a single global object of your app's process.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

> Return the context of the single, global Application object of the
>   current process.

So, when you launch the application, the system assigns a process to it. Doing `Context c = new Context()` will not get you the instance of that process.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html):

> Interface to global information about an application environment. This is an abstract class whose implementation is provided by the Android system. It allows access to application-specific resources and classes, as well as up-calls for application-level operations such as launching activities, broadcasting and receiving intents, etc.

So by using `getApplicationContext()`, you are calling the context object which is containing your application-specific resources.

Creating a new `Context` type object wouldn't make a sense since it's not containing information about your application environment.

Comment: application environment entails what exactly ?

Comment: I guess this article will explain it better for you http://www.simplecodestuffs.com/what-is-context-in-android/